# The app is not showing multiple marker of my adresses on map, It only show marker of my current location

Tags: android, google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3

I've just created Map on my android app. I have the list of addresses in my excel file and I save it as CSV file put it in res > raw. I have already read the CSV in my MapActivity. The problem is, when I run(App works fine) it only show marker of my current location but not showing the markers of my address list. What am I suppose to do?Did I miss something? Did I read my CSV file wrong? Hlp Pls.. Hope you understand me.

This is my CSVfile class inside of my Activity

```
public class CSVFile {
    InputStream inputStream;
    ArrayList<String[]> addressList = new ArrayList<>();


    public CSVFile(InputStream is) {
        this.inputStream = is;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> read() {
        addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                addressList.add(row);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return addressList;
    }
}
```

I call the class in OnCreate method . This is my Activity

```
public class ShowAllMap extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private InputStream inputStream;
private CSVFile csvFile;
ArrayList<String[]> hold;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_all_map);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setNumUpdates(1);


    inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.allmap);
    csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    hold = csvFile.read();
    if (hold != null) {
        for (int x = 0; x > this.hold.size(); x++) {

            try {
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ShowAllMap.this);
                List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(hold.get(x).toString(), 0);


                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    Address add = list.get(0);
                    double lat = add.getLatitude();
                    double lng = add.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng);
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                    mMap.addMarker(options);


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();//my fragment(R.id.maps)
}
.
.
.
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}

  @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    } else {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Toast.makeText(ShowAllMap.this, "Turn ON Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            onLocationChanged(location); 
        }
    }
}
```

This method is where I put my marker on Current Location.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .zoom(13f)
            .bearing(0.0f)
            .tilt(0.0f)
            .build();
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .title("I'm Here")
            .position(latLng);
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(position), null);

}
```

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: It does not have error. but it is not showing the marker at the addresses